# Firefox 31 not loading SSL site

Tags: nginx, openssl

Firefox 31 was released yesterday, and it seems like it has a problem with SSL:

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to api.joeyco.com. SSL peer selected a
cipher suite disallowed for the selected protocol version.
(Error code: ssl_error_cipher_disallowed_for_version)

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of
the received data could not be verified.
```

What I tried to resolve the problem: Update to "OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014", Reinstall nginx,
Reinstall PHP, Regenerate certificates.

I even went through [this page](http://nginx.com/blog/nginx-and-the-heartbleed-vulnerability/). What am I missing here? How can I find out for certain if nginx is actually using the correct OpenSSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your website has a problem of using insecure SSL ciphers.

You should configure the ciphers in your web server like this:

```
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers On;
ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;
```

Credit for the configration goes to https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/ .

You should also consider removing `SSLv3` from `ssl_protocols`, since it is not that safe either. IE6 users running Windows XP won't be able to connect to your site if you have `SSLv3` disabled.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. So which `ssl_protocols` do you recommend? Also when I check my site on https://www.digicert.com/help/index.htm it says still vulnerable to heartbleed, any idea why this could by.

Comment: I prefer to use only the TLS protocols in `ssl_protocols` You should open a new question on the Heartbleed issue at ServerFault. It seems that somehow your OpenSSL upgrade hasn't worked out correctly. You should provide OS & packages information in the question.

Answer (score -1):

It is not recommended to mess with that global security setting, but add trusted hosts instead if you really need to.

See this link for information about 'Renegotiation' (CVE-2009-3555):

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security:Renegotiation
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security:Renegotiation#security.ssl.renego_unrestricted_hosts

You can look at the security.ssl.renego_unrestricted_hosts pref on the about:config page and add the sites that you want to allow to the string value.

Separate multiple host names by a comma.

Comment: This doesn't really help in this case, because the server configuration problem affects all site users, and you cannot tell all site users to add things to trusted sites.